# Is there a way I can use .bash_aliases in a shell-scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

Is there a way I can use bash aliases from my .bash_aliases file within a shell-scripts?

I thought of something like including
`source "$HOME/.bash_aliases` into my script

but it does not work.

Comment: If you write your "aliases" as functions instead, they will work.   Using "$HOME"/... will make things very user-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-interactive shells don't expand aliases by default. You need to enable it:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```